# Using a regular expression to remove a uppercase letter if it's previous and next letter is lowercase?

Tags: python, regex, string, uppercase, lowercase

I am new in regular expression. I want to remove a uppercase letter if it has lowercase before and after it. If the input is `"I wilYl go theXre"` then the output should be `"I will go there"`. How can I get it?

Comment: Regex for uppercase before lowercase is [a-z][A-Z]

Comment: "I will go thereX" returns what?

Comment: `I wilYl go theXre` is input, `I will go there` is output. The `Y` and `X` are removed because it matches `[a-z][A-Z]`

Comment: How can  I write it in python?

Comment: What does it means is ok? Do you want to remove it too?

Comment: No only the uppercase which has lowercase before and after. Last uppercase is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookaround:

```
import re 

s='I wilYl go theXre'

print(re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])(?=[a-z])','',s))
#               ^ lookbehind     ^lookahead
```

Prints:

```
I will go there
```